# Datatable edit, delete common button on top with select row function without using editor datatables

Tags: php, datatables

[DataTable with edit delete buttons for separate rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQeER.png)

I am new to web development. I have learn to add, edit and delete DataTables. I want to have the functionality of editor data table (like common add edit delete buttons) to work for MySQL data.

I achieved adding new data by using bootstrap modals and connected to db via PHP. I don't know that for edit and delete options. So, I have implemented row wise edit delete buttons.

What am I doing wrong here? I need a code to select the row and edit from common edit button on top and that should change both client and server side.

And is it possible to do that without using Editor-DataTable?

Comment: Don't you think, it's not friendly to user? User has to select a raw (to catch the id) and again click on Edit or Delete button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the extensions, there is a [`Select`](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension that you can add that lets you select rows from your table. After that, you could find out what rows are selected on the button press event and create a modal to make your changes or however you want to handle that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    select: true
  });


  $("#deleteBtn").on("click", function() {
    selectRows = table.rows({
      selected: true
    });
    //perform your delete CRUD update.

    //remove from UI
    selectRows.remove().draw();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/select/js/dataTables.select.js?_=9a6592f8d74f8f520ff7b22342fa1183"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/select/css/select.dataTables.css?_=9a6592f8d74f8f520ff7b22342fa1183.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="container">
  <button id="deleteBtn">Delete</button>
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks rich..answer is useful for client side. since iam new to development ,i dont know to place the selected row id to delete on server side..should i use this  ->   DT_RowId: "id" ??

Comment: It depends on how you're backend is set up. The row ID in datatables probably does not relate to your backend, as it is a number being generated by the datatable.  You'd probably need to identify what values are unique identifiers. It looks like S.No. would be that here, but I just can't know that. Personally, I just pass down the row id from my DB and store that as a hidden column so that I can call something like `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID='id';` with my SQL.